# How to Hadoop Map Reduce entire file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've played around with various streamin map reduce word count examples where Hadoop/Hbase appears to take a large file and break it (at a line break) equally between the nodes.  Then it submits each line of the partial document to the map portion of my code.  My question is when I have lots of little unstructured and semi-structured documents, how do I get Hadoop to submit the entire document to my map code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File split are caluculated by the InputFormat.getSplits. So for the each input file it gets number of splits and each split is submitted to a mapper. Now based on the InputFormat Mapper will process the input split.

We have different types of Input Formats consider for example TextInputFormat which will take text files as input and for each split, it supplies line offset as key and entire line as value to map method in Mapper. Similarly for other InputFormats.

Now if you have many small files, say each file is less than the block size. Then each file will be supplied to a different mapper. If the file size exceeds the block size then it will be split into two blocks and executed on two blocks.

Consider an example where input files each are 1MB and you have 64 such files. Also assume that your block size is 64MB.

Now you will have 64 mappers kicked off for each file.

Consider you have 100 MB file and you have 2 such files.

Now your 100 MB file will be split into 64MB + 36MB and 4 mappers will be kicked off.